# a4j rerender inputText onSubmit event

Tags: jsf, facelets, ajax4jsf

I tried different combinations to just rerender the result pannel.

it works fine with

```
<h:form><a4j:region>
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.keyword}">
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="results" eventsQueue="search" oncomplete="initResults();" />
</h:inputText>
</a4j:region>
</h:form>
```

But i just want to submit it when enter is pressed. So i tried

```
<h:form reRender="results" eventsQueue="search" oncomplete="initResults();"><a4j:region>
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.keyword}"/>
</a4j:region>
</h:form>
```

that returned an empty result even if it shouldn't be empty and

```
<a4j:region>
<h:form>
<a4j:support event="onsubmit" reRender="results" eventsQueue="search" oncomplete="initResults();" />
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.keyword}"/>
</h:form>
</a4j:region>
```

was reloading the whole page and not the result panel only (but results where shown). I even tried to add `<h:form onSubmit="return false;">` in the last example. [EDIT: ok that return false is just overwritten by the AJAX support call]

How do i make my inputText field rerender when "enter" is pressed. (so the form is submitted) but don't want to submit the form.

**EDIT:** again my bad, i simplified the example code here too much. i had a second element with a4j:support in the same form, since i removed the a4j tag there and changed the onchange event to a form submit, too, it is working.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selectedMetaCategory}" onchange="this.form.submit();">
  <a4j:support ...
  <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.metaSelectItems}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<a4j:region>
<a4j:form onsubmit="reRenderResults();">
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.keyword}"/>
</a4j:form>
<a4j:jsFunction name="reRenderResults" reRender="results" eventsQueue="search" oncomplete="initResults();" />
</a4j:region>
```

Comment: did it a different way like i wrote in EDIT above, but because of my missing information in my question, i mark your answer correct.